# Login.php not redirecting

Tags: php, login-script

On this login page when I try to login it gives a blank page. Though login is successful as on clicking the profile tab the `dashboard.php` is visible. Also this whole thing works just fine in my WAMP server.

What is causing this issue?

```
<?php

ob_start();
$host="localhost"; // Host name 
$username="######"; // Mysql username 
$password="######"; // Mysql password 
$db_name="devspan_Users"; // Database name 
$tbl_name="Members"; // Table name 

// Connect to server and select databse.
$con=mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect");

mysql_query("CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS ".$db_name);
mysql_select_db("$db_name",$con)or die("cannot select DB"); 



if(mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SHOW TABLES LIKE '".$tbl_name."'",$con))==0)
{
$sql="CREATE TABLE Members(
id int(4) NOT NULL auto_increment,
username varchar(65) NOT NULL default '',
password varchar(65) NOT NULL default '',
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)";
mysql_query($sql,$con);
}

// Define $myusername and $mypassword 
$myusername=$_POST['username']; 
$mypassword=$_POST['password']; 

// To protect MySQL injection
$myusername = stripslashes($myusername);
$mypassword = stripslashes($mypassword);
$myusername = mysql_real_escape_string($myusername);
$mypassword = mysql_real_escape_string($mypassword);
$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE username='$myusername' and password='$mypassword'";
$result=mysql_query($sql,$con);

// Mysql_num_row is counting table row
$count=mysql_num_rows($result);

// If result matched $myusername and $mypassword
if($count==1){
// Register 
session_start();
$_SESSION["myusername"]=$myusername;
$_SESSION["mypassword"]=$mypassword; 
header("location:dashboard.php");
}
else {
echo "Wrong Username or Password";
}
ob_end_flush();
?>
```

Comment: `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` will likely produce, "Cannot modify headers - headers already sent"

Comment: You've got some serious cargo-cult programming going on in there...

Comment: The problem may very well be inside `dashboard.php` is `session_start();` in that page also?

Comment: Just put `if(!headers_sent()): header("location:dashboard.php"); endif;` if it doesn't fire, you know your headers have been sent. Then refer back to my initial comment.

Comment: Why does every beginner try to build horrible logins by themselves ? I mean, this is a serious security issue, so why you don't use existing scripts ? You code is horrible, extremely outdated in in general totally wrong and insecure.

Comment: @Panique : I made this by looking at examples in the web. Can you please provide me some links of better scripts? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update: The Problem was with my hosting not my code. sql queries took a lifetime to fetch data, hence the page did not load. Solution: Changed my Hosting service.

Answer (score 0):

In this block of code:

```
// If result matched $myusername and $mypassword
if($count==1){
// Register 
session_start();
$_SESSION["myusername"]=$myusername;
$_SESSION["mypassword"]=$mypassword; 
header("location:dashboard.php");
}
else {
echo "Wrong Username or Password";
}
ob_end_flush();
?>'
```

What is `?>'` at the end for?  Just remove that & try again. Also, note I changed the `header` line as part of the cleanup to be `header('Location: dashboard.php');` Here it is cleaned up.

```
ob_start();

$host="localhost"; // Host name 
$username="######"; // Mysql username 
$password="######"; // Mysql password 
$db_name="devspan_Users"; // Database name 
$tbl_name="Members"; // Table name 

// Connect to server and select databse.
$con=mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect");

mysql_query("CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS " . $db_name);
mysql_select_db("$db_name", $con) or die("cannot select DB"); 

if (mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SHOW TABLES LIKE '" . $tbl_name . "'",$con))= = 0) {
  $sql = "CREATE TABLE"
       . " Members(id int(4) NOT NULL auto_increment,"
       . " username varchar(65) NOT NULL default '',"
       . " password varchar(65) NOT NULL default '',"
       . " PRIMARY KEY (`id`)"
       . ")"
       ;
  mysql_query($sql,$con);
}

// Define $myusername and $mypassword 
$myusername=$_POST['username']; 
$mypassword=$_POST['password']; 

// To protect MySQL injection
$myusername = stripslashes($myusername);
$mypassword = stripslashes($mypassword);
$myusername = mysql_real_escape_string($myusername);
$mypassword = mysql_real_escape_string($mypassword);

$sql = "SELECT *"
    . " FROM $tbl_name"
    . " WHERE"
    . " username='" . $myusername . "'"
    . " AND password='" . $mypassword . "'"
    ;

$result = mysql_query($sql, $con);

// Mysql_num_row is counting table row
$count = mysql_num_rows($result);

// If result matched $myusername and $mypassword
if ($count == 1){
  // Register 
  session_start();
  $_SESSION["myusername"] = $myusername;
  $_SESSION["my password"] = $mypassword; 
  header('Location: dashboard.php');
}
else {
  echo "Wrong Username or Password";
}
ob_end_flush();
```

Comment: `What is ?>'` --- I did remove the `'` in an earlier edit, so I wasn't entirely sure if that was actually part of the OP's code, or if it was a typo, which happens often.

Comment: The OP will have to do it, I won't setup a DB for this to test it. It's up to the OP not us. ;-)